# Excel VBA solver. Equation isn't solving

Tags: vba, excel

this is probably a very simple question to someone that knows what they are doing, but I am new to using VBA solver function and it is proving to be a pain.

I have this formula is cell C1 =3*A1^2-2*A1^3 and have a set number in B1, let’s say 0.5.

I’d like to use Solver to change cell A1, currently set as 0, until C1 = B1

I have tried playing with sample code but no joy, I currently stand with the code below but it does nothing

```
Sub solveTest()

Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
SolverReset
SolverOptions precision:=0.001
SolverOK setCell:=Range("C1"), maxMinVal:=3, byChange:=Range("A1")
SolverAdd cellRef:=Range("B1"), relation:=2, formulaText:=Range("C1")
SolverSolve userFinish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using the Solver wizard to confirm if there is a valid solution to your query? If there is can you run the code line by line by pressing `F8` and review what if anything the code is doing? Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set maxMinVal to 3, you are saying you want it to converge to a particular value. But then in your code you haven't said what that value is. I see you're implying it with the constraint you then add, but I doubt it guesses it from that. I'd suggest getting rid of the constraint and ammending the SolverOk line as follows:

```
Sub solveTest2()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    SolverReset
    SolverOptions precision:=0.001
    SolverOK setCell:=Range("C1"), maxMinVal:=3, valueof:=Range("B1").Value, byChange:=Range("A1")
    SolverSolve userFinish:=True

End Sub
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/843304